# In Naruto, why were women chosen to be Jinchuuriki of the Kyuubi?

Tags: naruto

So we are told that during pregnancy the seal weakens. And we can see that in the Kushina episodes. But if the seal weakens during pregnancy, why would they even allow women to become Jinchuuriki? Isn't it way safer to just appoint a man to the role? Do they have anything to gain from appointing a woman? I mean.. Kushina was a woman... the Kyuubi's previous Jinchuuriki was also a woman. Why is that?

When discussing who the next Jinchuuriki will be did  nobody raise they hands and go like "That's not a good choice at all! You guys do realize if she wants t have kids we'll need to organize a super-secret plan to exploit this. To which I'm sure somebody said "It's OK, it's not like some random naked man is going to attack us while she's giving birth and exploit this mechanic.... right?"

Comment: I think they just need someone to be the Jinchuuriki, and so the gender doesn't matter.

Comment: It's probably not easy to find suitable hosts to be Jinchuuriki. Both Kushina and Mito were from the Uzumaki clan whose members are known to have strong life forces and thus they were chosen. Besides, I remember the 4th Raikage mentioning that Jinchuuriki are usually related to the Kage (siblings/spouse). Perhaps Kushina was chosen with the hope that she would become the spouse of the 4th? I'm not sure if there are any canon evidence though..

Comment: @zyten It is explicitly stated in the Anime that Kushina was bought for the sole purpose of being the JIchuriki when the first's wife passed away. This was before Kushina and Minato got together.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Though the wording may have been poor, this is a valid question for Narutoverse, because choosing a women as a Jinchuriki provides an obvious disadvantage, weakening of seal during Childbirth. I think this can be a better question if wording is improved.

Comment: @Arcane the seal only weakens during childbirth, but that's only childbirth. It's not like ALL women Jinchuriki are going to get pregnant. If the people are so worried about the seal weakening, then don't make a women a Jinchuriki. Or the people could do something to avoid the girl getting pregnant, like maybe hiding her away from all people like they do to some men Jinchuuriki.

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru The OP is asking exactly the same question. "If the people are so worried about the seal weakening, then don't make women a Jinchuriki". My answer below tries to explain some reasons why women were chosen as Jinchuriki DESPITE the chances of seal weakening.

Answer (score 4):

There have been three known Jinchuriki for Kurama, all from the Uzumaki clan. Mito, Kushina and Naruto.

After Madara and Hashirama's final battle in the Valley of the End, Hashirama realized that Kurama was too dangerous to be walking alone in the world. Mito chose to seal Kyuubi within herself because of her knowledge of Uzumaki clan's Sealing Techniques, Exceptional Chakra and lifeforce, and the fact being close to First Hokage meant that he could control the situation if the seal weakened and Kyuubi went on rampage. Thus Mito was kind of convenient and obvious choice at that time.

Naruto on the otherhand was on the opposite end of spectrum. Minato was against the ropes and realized that the village needed Kyuubi's power to fight the threat posed by supposed Madara Uchiha. Naruto had the Uzumaki blood and sealing only half of Kurama allowed him more control as well.

**Thus only Kushina's case was special, since it was deliberated and chosen specifically for being the Jinchuriki.** The reasons of this are explained as follows.

- Kushina was chosen as the successor towards the twilight years of the clan. Uzumaki clan had almost disintegrated and a suitable successor would be very hard to find. Thus Kushina may have been the **ONLY choice**!
- Mito was a tested host for the Kyuubi and thus Leaf elders may have decided that the next Jinchuriki should be as close to Mito as possible. A special Kunoichi from Uzumaki clan with exceptional chakra? Thats what they were looking for.
- Kushina was eventually told why she had to leave her home of Uzushio and go to Konoha; because of her **special chakra**, she was to be the next jinchūriki of the Nine-Tailed Demon Fox. This can be the Uzumaki chakra or some other criteria, we don't know. (Source - Naruto chapter 500)
- Before the transfer was performed, Mito advised Kushina that **love was the only way to tame the Nine-Tails and overcome its hate**. Kyuubi was known as the incarnation of hate in the world and thus Mito may have felt that only a Kunoichi could control all the hate inside much more easily then any other ninja.

Answer (score 0):

Women are not best choice for jinchuriki.But kushina and hashirama's whife are special cases. Because both of them are usumaki clan members.they have special sealing powers and technics. And also kushina was selected because of her large amount of chakra.